# Regular Expressions in VbScript?

Tags: regex, email, asp-classic, vbscript

Does VbScript have a native implementation for Regex? I need to validate e-mail addresses on an old ASP application.

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This example is by AlexCuse from [LessThanDot](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Using_Regular_Expressions_For_Pattern_Matching_in_Access)

```
Function ValidEmail(ByVal emailAddress) 

'this function will use regular expressions to check an '
'email address for validity '

'instantiate regex object container, output boolean '
Dim objRegEx, retVal 

'using late binding, vbscript reference is not required '
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 

'.pattern -looks for a valid email address '
With objRegEx 
      .Pattern = "^\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$" 
      .IgnoreCase = True 
End With 

retVal = objRegEx.Test(emailAddress) 

'get rid of RegEx object '
Set objRegEx = Nothing 

ValidEmail = retVal 

End Function
```

Comment: Thats a crummy match pattern, but easily fixed.

Comment: haha I haven't used that code in quite a while.  But would you mind sharing how you'd fix the match pattern?  I don't use regular expressions too often but always looking for tips.

Comment: This accepts the illegal "e@.r..com" but not the legal "info@some.museum", and no IDN. Try to send to "mailtest@例え.テスト" (or converted to punny-code: "mailtest@xn--r8jz45g.xn--zckzah")

Comment: Since the question is tagged VBScript I'm surprised how many upvoted a VB6 implementation.

Answer (score 20):

Since the top answer here is in VB6 I thought I'd add one here in VBScript (since that's what the question is asking for):-

```
Option Explicit

Function GetEmailValidator()

  Set GetEmailValidator = New RegExp

  GetEmailValidator.Pattern = "^((?:[A-Z0-9_%+-]+\.?)+)@((?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4})$"

  GetEmailValidator.IgnoreCase = True

End Function

Dim EmailValidator : Set EmailValidator = GetEmailValidator()
```

Now some tests:-

```
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("") = False
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test(" ") = False
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("somebody@domain.co.uk") = True
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("someone@domain.com") = True
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("some.body@domain.co.uk") = True
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("broken@domain..co.uk") = False
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("@oops.co.uk") = False
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("name") = False
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("name@uk") = False
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("name@uk") = False
Response.Write EmailValidator.Test("name@domain.abcde") = False
```

Comment: this was a bit slow for some reason (IE 9), I simplified a bit to ^[A-Z0-9_%+-\.]+@[A-Z0-9-\.]+\.[A-Z]{2,10}$

Comment: Apostrophe is a valid character in the left part of the email, like Conan.O'Brien@teamcoco.com yet you're not allowing it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sure does. [Here's Microsoft's documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Like other said, yes.  I just wanted to put you at the devguru [vbscript](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/vbscript/quickref/vbscript_list.html) docs, I find they tend to be the good place to get quick vbscript answers.  This is there section on the [Regexp](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/vbscript/quickref/regexp.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript has a built-in RegExp object, which is Microsoft's implementation of JavaScript regular expressions.  I have an [article about the VBScript RegExp object](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) on my website that explains how to use it.