# Copying all @mentions and #hashtags from column A to Columns B and C in Excel

Tags: excel, twitter, extract, vba

I have a really large database of tweets. Most of the tweets have multiple #hashtags and @mentions. I want all the #hashtags separated with a space in one column and all the @mentions in another column. I already know how to extract the first occurrence of a `#hashtag` and a `@mention`. But I don't know to get them all? Some of the tweets have as much as 8 #hashtags. Manually going through the tweets and copy/pasting the #hashtags and @mentions seem an impossible task for over 5,000 tweets.

Here is an example of what I want. I have Column A and I want a macro that would populate columns B and C. (I'm on Windows &, Excel 2010)

```
Column A
-----------
Dear #DavidStern, @spurs put a quality team on the floor and should have beat the @heat. Leave #Pop alone. #Spurs a classy organization.
Live broadcast from @Nacho_xtreme: "Papelucho Radio"http://mixlr.com nachoxtreme-radio … #mixlr #pop #dance
"Since You Left" by @EmilNow now playing on KGUP 106.5FM. Listen now on http://www.kgup1065.com  #Pop #Rock
Family Night #battleofthegenerations Dad has the #Monkeys Mom has #DonnieOsman @michaelbuble for me #Dubstep for the boys#Pop for sissy
@McKinzeepowell @m0ore21 I love that the PNW and the Midwest are on the same page!! #Pop
```

I want Column B to look like This:

```
Column B
--------
#DavidStern #Pop #Spurs
#mixlr #pop #dance
#Pop #Rock
#battleofthegenerations #Monkeys #DonnieOsman #Dubstep #Pop
#pop
```

And Column C to look like this:

```
Column C:
----------
@spurs @heat
@Nacho_xtreme
@EmilNow
@michaelbuble
@McKinzeepowell @m0ore21
```

Comment: How much are you paying :) ? Seriously, it would help if you could describe what you've tried and your level of programming skills: creating macros, using VBA, using the Excel object model, and regular expressions. From the FAQ: **Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.**. Also, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using regular expressions.

You can use regular expressions within VBA by adding a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` from `Tools -> References`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361248/regular-expressions-in-vbscript) is a good starting point, with a number of useful links.

---

**Updated**

After adding a reference to the `Regular Expressions` library, put the following function in a VBA module:

```
Public Function JoinMatches(text As String, start As String)
Dim re As New RegExp, matches As MatchCollection, match As match
re.pattern = start & "\w*"
re.Global = True
Set matches = re.Execute(text)
For Each match In matches
    JoinMatches = JoinMatches & " " & match.Value
Next
JoinMatches = Mid(JoinMatches, 2)
End Function
```

Then, in cell `B1` put the following formula (for the hashtags):

```
=JoinMatches(A1,"#")
```

In column `C1` put the following formula:

```
=JoinMatches(A1,"@")
```

Now you can copy just the formulas all the way down.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could convert text to columns using the other character @, then against for #s and then concatenate the rest of the text back together for column A, if you are not familiar with regular expressions see (@Zev-Spitz)