# How to get average reply time from ping command?

Tags: vbscript, ping

I need to know how to get average reply time from using ping command in the vbs.

I found out that I can get all ping output just executing this command but may be I can just get my time data and calculate in variable without using string handling.

```vb
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("ping -n 2 -w 1000 " & strTarget)
  strPingResults = LCase(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
```

Comment: You could probably use [`RegExp` to build a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/361248/692942) and match just the output you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend shelling out to `ping.exe` and then parsing the output. Use WMI instead:

```
target = 'somecomputer'
n = 2

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE address='" & target & "'"

rspTime = 0
cnt = 0
For i = 1 To n
    For Each pingStatus In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
        If Not IsNull(pingStatus.StatusCode) Or pingStatus.StatusCode = 0 Then
            rspTime = rspTime + pingStatus.ResponseTime
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

If cnt > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Average response time: " & (rspTime / cnt)
Else
    WScript.Echo "Host unreachable"
End If
```

Comment: Keep forgetting all of the stuff you can do with WMI. +1

Comment: `If IsNull(pingStatus.StatusCode) Or pingStatus.StatusCode<>0 Then` should be `If Not IsNull(pingStatus.StatusCode) Or pingStatus.StatusCode = 0 Then`otherwise you will get always `"Host unreachable"` ????

Comment: @Hackoo Yes, it should. Thanks for the heads up.